# CMake: Use variables from existing Makefile of 3rdparty library

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm facing the following scenario:

- Existing project which uses `cmake`
- External 3rdparty library which only comes with Makefiles

The difference of my situation compared to existing questions is that I don't need to have cmake to build the 3rdparty library via the Makefile. Instead, the 3rdparty library provides a `library.mk` Makefile which has variables like `LIB_SRCS` and `LIB_INCS` containing all source and header files required to compile the library.

My idea is to include the `library.mk` into the project's `CMakeLists.txt` and then adding those `$(LIB_SRCS)` and `$(LIB_INCS)` to `target_sources()`.

My question: How can I include `library.mk` into the existing `CMakeLists.txt` to get access to the `$(LIB_SRCS)` and `$(LIB_INCS)` for adding them to `target_sources()`? I'm looking for something like this:

```
include("/path/to/library.mk")   # Somehow include the library's `library.mk` to expose variables to cmake.

add_executable(my_app)

target_sources(
    my_app
    PRIVATE
        main.c
        $(LIB_SRCS)    # Add 3rd-party library source files
        $(LIB_INCS)    # Add 3rd-party library header files
)
```

Using `include()` does not work as the `library.mk` is not a CMake list/file.

Comment: "*The difference of my situation compared to existing questions is that I don't need to have cmake to build the 3rdparty library via the Makefile.*" -- why not?  That would result in your program using the library *as* a library, which is normally the mode intended by a library project.  It's a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't be sure that your target system will even have Make on it, the only option is to parse the strings out of the .mk file, which might be easy if the variables are set directly as a list of filenames, or really hard if they are set with expansions of other variables, conditionals, etc.  Do this with `FILE(STRINGS)` [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#strings).

Your plan will only work if the Makefiles are trivial, and do not set important compiler flags, define preprocessor variables, modify the include directory, etc.  And if they really are trivial, skip the parsing, and just do something like `aux_source_directory(<dir> <variable>)` to collect all the sources from the library directory.

You might also consider building and maintaining a CMakeLists.txt for this third-party library.  Do the conversion once, and store it as a branch off of the "vendor" main branch in your version control system.  Whenever you update, update the vendor branch from upstream, and merge or rebase your modifications.  Or just store it in your existing project, referring to the source directory of the 3rd-party stuff.